# how can I introduce myself in emails?

Tags: expressions

My question is, if I'm writing an email to some one for the first time, do I introduce myself with sentance like:'I'm ...'? or like in the phone:'This is...'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of convention, but personally, I try to avoid opening with "I'm..." or "my name is...".  If you're emailing someone you have a connection to, mention that and how/when you met the person.  Your email address and signature will have your name, so it's better to link your face to the name, rather than write it out again.  If you're emailing someone cold, I'd open with your purpose - why your emailing them.  If your position or job title is important, perhaps slip your name in there.  Focus on the purpose though, the key to good email is getting the point across in less text.